# Select three different things from three diffrent tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wanna a query to get first_name of students and first_name of teachers which have the most courses with each other with the number of these courses.

Table Student:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
id    INT    AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
last_name    VARCHAR(255),
email    VARCHAR(255)    UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Table Teacher:

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher(
id    INT    AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
last_name    VARCHAR(255),
email    VARCHAR(255)    UNIQUE,
degree    VARCHAR(10)    NUT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Table Course:

```
CREATE TABLE Course(
id    INT    AUTO_INCREMENT,
code    INT    NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
st_id    INT,
teach_id    INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY st_id REFERENCES Student (id),
FOREIGN KEY teach_id REFERENCES Teacher (id)
);
```

Is the below query correct? i.e. Can I use 3 SELECT in a query?

query1:

```
SELECT      S.first_name
FROM        Student AS S
INNER JOIN  Course AS C
        ON  C.st_id = S.id
SELECT      T.first_name        
FROM        Teacher AS T
INNER JOIN  Course AS CC
        ON  CC.teach_id = T.id
SELECT      COUNT(*)
FROM        Course
WHERE       Course.st_id = S.id
AND         Course.teach_id = T.id
GROUP BY    COUNT(*)
ORDER BY   DESC;
```

query2:

```
SELECT     S.first_name, T.first_name, COUNT(*)
FROM       Student AS S, Teacher AS T, Course
WHERE      Course.st_id = S.id
AND        Course.teach_id = T.id
GROUP BY   COUNT(*)
ORDER BY   DESC;
```

If the above queries are not correct(probably the first one is wrong) guide me to correct answer, please.

**NOTE:** If the ordering isn't unique, order by the name of teachers first, then order by the name of the students(for clarity but not important so much to me).

Comment: Can you provide some (simple) sample data to explain what your question means?

Comment: @GordonLinoff for example student S1 has 3 courses with Teacher T1, student S2 has 2 courses with Teacher T1 and ... is it clear? I add a new note to the question.

Comment: have you tried running your queries? what is the result?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I get jus "wrong answer" and it doesn't say anything about why it is wrong.

Comment: wrong answer is coming from the tool you use to check if your homework are correct?

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is an online judge. for other languages, it has some other options like wrong answer, time limit, and runtime error. but in SQL I haven't seen these options.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.first_name, t.id, s.first_name, s.id, COUNT(c.id) AS course_count
  FROM course c
  JOIN student s ON c.st_id = s.id
  JOIN teacher t ON c.teach_id = t.id
 GROUP BY t.id, s.id
 ORDER BY t.first_name, s.first_name
```

The essential data is contained in the Courses table, with the Student and Teacher tables only required for gathering the names. This query joins the 3 tables in question, computing the count of courses shared by teachers and students.

Comment: how this is supposed to fix OP's issue? adding some explanation will help future users to solve the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is closer to being right but it has some issues. I would recommend using JOIN statements rather than implied joins. This makes the query easier to read.

Something like this should work:

```
  SELECT t.first_name,
         t.id,
         s.first_name,
         s.id,
         COUNT(*) AS course_count
    FROM Course c
    JOIN Student s ON c.st_id = s.id
    JOIN Teacher t ON c.teach_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, s.id
ORDER BY course_count DESC, t.first_name, s.first_name;
```

You need to add a group by in order to get your count on a per student basis. Putting the group by on the id columns rather than the name makes sure you get counts on unique students and teachers in case you have multiple records in your table with the same first name. I am also adding the id columns to the select for the same reason, but these are not necessary and can be removed without affecting the accuracy of the query.